# Will I fail my background check?

Tags: background-check

On my resume for the Univeristy/Degree I put years 2015-2019 but in my background check through a 3rd party company I put the years 2018-2019 which is the correct years I attended the university and graduated with my degree.

Because of this discrepancy, the 3rd party informed the new employer and the new employer are asking me to comment on this.

I told my new employer the dates I put in my background verification are correct and the degree/university I put down are the same in my resumes and background check.. it’s only the years that is a discrepancy.

Would I fail because of this? I’m so nervous

EDIT: After explaining the discrepancies they’ve gotten back to me and gave me the next steps for onboarding!

Comment: Which dates are the correct dates?

Comment: Tell _us_ why you chose to write two different sets of dates.

Answer (score 5):

> Would I fail because of this? I’m so nervous

Since a background check is not a globally codified process, we cannot tell you. The company will decide what they do with that information.

From an employers perspective, I would be interested in what you did between 2015 and 2018 if you did not do what you said you did. Be prepared for that question as a best-case-scenario.

Comment: @RedRum So you were studying from 2015-2019 but from 2015-2018 you were studying at a different school?  I think if you said that to your employer you would be fine.  You may also want to note that on your resume somehow, that your degree is a 4-year degree program and you changed schools mid-degree.

Comment: @Ertai87 I think the best way to indicate this on the resume would be to just say "Graduated in 2019."

Comment: @RedRum Don't send them another CV.  Just give them an explanation: "I was studying at school X from 2015-2018.  I transferred to school Y, where I completed my degree, in 2018, and I studied there for 1 year".  You should update your CV and keep a personal record so this doesn't happen again in future.

Comment: @RedRum If it was me, I would also apologize for the inconvenience and confusion, because now they're going to have to background check you again at schools X and Y.  But also I'm Canadian and we apologize for everything.

Comment: CVs are not just checked for veracity; carelessness or vagueness can tell against the writer just as much as outright falsehoods.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that is good points